# how to use CUDA Pinned memory from tensorflow python library

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently looking into running tensorflow on GPU. I was reading about CUDA pinned memory.

I was not able to find anyway to set this when using tensorflow python library.
Any idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's automatically used for any memcpy between CPU and GPU. If you want more sophisticated functionalities, you can write a kernel that explicitly uses them.