# How to fully disable pinned memory use in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43352508/1575836) mentioned, tensorflow automatically uses pinned memory to accelerate data transfer between host memory and gpu memory. Now I want to test the benefit from pin memory use. Is there a way to fully disable it?

In pytorch, the class [DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html?highlight=dataloader#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) has the parameter *pin_memory* to choose the pin memory use. In tensorflow, I find gpu option [force_gpu_compatible](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GPUOptions#force_gpu_compatible) to force enable all pin memory use. Here is the [explanation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/456fbc0e498e3d10604973de9f46ca48d62267cc/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L88) for it. Is there any option could fully disable pin memory use?